# ActiveAdmin Passing Resource from Controller to Render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am building a rails application using ActiveAdmin, and want to build a form for a custom action in the controller. I am trying to pass @listings from a collective_action to the rendered file, allowing me to edit multiple records at once. The @listings are based on an ActiveRecord query which draws record IDs from the URL.

It seems to be successfully accessing the parameters from the URL, and querying the database. When the form is served to the browser however, it is not able to produce the values of listing.title. Any ideas?

Here is my Listing.rb:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Listing do
    collection_action :batch_upload do
     ids = params[:id]
     @listings = []
     @listings = Listing.find(ids)
       render template: 'listings/edit_batch'
    end
end
```

Here is my edit_batch.html.haml:

```
= semantic_form_for :listing, :url => {:controller => 'listings', :action => 'batch_upload'}, :html=>{:method=>:put} do |f|
    -@listings.each do |listing|
        =f.hidden_field :id, :value => listing.id
        =f.input :title, :value => listing.title
    =f.submit "Submit"
```

Comment: So the form displays an id but no title?

Comment: yes it displays id, but no title. i'm not sure if the field names are right...they are listing[id] and listing[title] for every iteration of the form...

Answer (score 1):

If the form is correctly displaying `listing.id` but not `listing.title` then I suspect the record does not have title set, or listing does not have a title attribute.

To check, run the Rails console and find the record using the id from the form:

```
$ Listing.find(1)
```

Check the returned object to see whether it is missing the title.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... I tried this and it returns a record including a title...any other ideas?

Comment: Ok, have you tried printing out the `listing` inside the form, for example, after line 2? Does it return a record with a title here?

Comment: as a matter of fact, it does....what could that mean? something wrong with my input code?

Answer (score 1):

I changed the code to the input so that it accesses its html directly and it worked:

```
=f.input :title, :input_html => { :value => listing.title }
```

Comment: Great! Hope the debugging helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Using Formtastic's `inputs` block might help simplify the inputs for each listing. Doing so will allow the form to create attribute fields for each Listing object.

```
# edit_batch.html.haml
= semantic_form_for :listing, :url => {:controller => 'listings', :action => 'batch_upload'}, :html=>{:method=>:put} do |f|

    - @listings.each_with_index do |listing, index|

      f.inputs for: listing, for_options: { index: index } do |l|
        = l.input :id, as: :hidden
        = l.input :title

    = f.submit "Submit"
```

The `:for` and `:for_options` scope inputs fields to a specific object.